# ESP32 Access Point using ESPAsyncWebServer, how to send multiple parameters between submenu and main (index) menu while still retaining page layout?

Tags: esp32, web-server, http

I am trying to figure out how to get requests (or whatever they are called) to display in the serial monitor, yet not change the HTML page bodies.

The user selects their choices in the submenu (`selection`). Once clicking the submit button there, they return to the original main index menu and simultaneously the query parameters are sent to the ESP32 of the user's selections.

Based off another very similar question I asked, it works so that the query parameters (in the URL) can be seen in the serial monitor. Although, then the main menu is cleared out and left with "message sent".

Alternatively, the main menu can remain the same, but the query parameters are not sent. So one works but not the other, and vise versa.

The files are below and here: https://github.com/adamelli/MinimalExamples/tree/main/22-1-25_query_parameters_submitButton

## File structure

sketch (folder)

- sketch.ino
- data (folder)

  - index.html
  - selection.html

## sketch.ino

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>
#include <SPIFFS.h>
#include <painlessMesh.h>

const char* ssid = "Wireless Controller";
const char* password = "12345678";

// User stub
void sendMessage() ; // Prototype so PlatformIO doesn't complain

Task taskSendMessage( TASK_SECOND * 1 , TASK_FOREVER, &sendMessage );

void sendMessage() {
  taskSendMessage.setInterval( random( TASK_SECOND * 1, TASK_SECOND * 5 ));
}

AsyncWebServer server(80);

void notFound(AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
    request->send(404, "text/plain", "Not found");
}
IPAddress IP(192, 168, 1, 1);
IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 1, 1);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);



  // Initialize SPIFFS
  if (!SPIFFS.begin(true))
  {
    Serial.println("An Error has occurred while mounting SPIFFS");
    return;
  }



  WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);
  delay(500);
  WiFi.softAPConfig(IP, gateway, subnet);
  IPAddress IP = WiFi.softAPIP();
  Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
  Serial.println(IP);










  server.on("/selection.html", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest * request) {
    request->send(SPIFFS, "/selection.html", String(), false );
  });


    

// Main menu index page works
//  server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest * request) {
//    request->send(SPIFFS, "/index.html", String(), false );
//  });





// Query parameters works
  server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest * request)
  {

    int paramsNr = request->params();
    Serial.println(paramsNr);

    for (int i = 0; i < paramsNr; i++)
    {
      AsyncWebParameter* p = request->getParam(i);
      Serial.print("Param name: ");
      Serial.println(p->name());
      
      Serial.print("Param value: ");
      Serial.println(p->value());
      
      Serial.println("------");
    }

    request->send(200, "text/plain", "message received");
  });






  server.begin();
}



void loop() {}
```

## index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <h1>Main Menu</h1>
  

<p><a href="/selection.html"><button class="button">Selection</button></a></p>

<p><a href="/notMinimal.html"><button class="button">Oblivion</button></a></p>


</body>
</html>
```

## selection.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body> 
<!-- -->
<form action="/" method="get"> 



    <label for="size" style="font-size: 22px">Shape Size:</label>

    <select name="size" id="size" style="font-size: 22px;">
      <option value="1"> 1   </option>
      <option value="2"> 1/2 </option> 
        </select>


    <p><label for="speed" style="font-size: 22px">Speed:</label>
    
    <select name="speed" id="speed" style="font-size: 24px">
      <option value="1">          Slowest </option>
      <option value="2" selected> Regular </option>
    </select></p>




  <p><a href="/selection"><button class="submit" name="circle" value="3">Circle</button></a></p>
  
  <p><a href="/selection"><button class="submit" name="square" value="4">Square</button></a></p>



</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The data files must be uploaded via "Tools" → "ESP32 Sketch Data Upload".

How can the definitions, `server.on("/"` be combined so the data (size/speed/shape) is viewable in the serial monitor AND where the main and submenu remain the same (with their buttons)?

I have tried...

- putting `request->send(SPIFFS, "/selection.html", String(), false);` and    `request->send(200, "text/plain", "message received");` together inside  `server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest * request)`
- sending different stuff for `request->send(200, "text/plain", "message received");` even though I still do not understand how to get it to submit data, and return to the main menu, without clearing it out with a new message (various trial and error combinations either did not allow it to compile or just made one of the pages "Not found")
- messing with HTML stuff (nothing changed)

Comment: So - if I understand you correctly - you want to just normally serve your index.html, until parameters are provided with the request. Then you want to output them to serial and serve the "message received" text. Is that correct?

Comment: Nope. The user selects their choices in the submenu (selection). Once clicking the submit button there, they return to the original main index menu and simultaneously (in the background) the query parameters are sent to the ESP32 of their selections. (When I replace "message received" with "" it just shows a blank main index menu.)

Comment: This is nothing to do with Arduino. This is all about Javascript and [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) calls.

Comment: Please don't repost, does [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/88538/esp32-access-point-and-http-web-server-how-to-send-multiple-parameters) answer your question?

Comment: According to your original post https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/88538/esp32-access-point-and-http-web-server-how-to-send-multiple-parameters, you had a duplicate route handler for `/`, what you need to do is to change your param handling route to something else , say,  `server.on("/submit"` and also change your form submission action on selection.html to `<form action="/submit" method="get">`. It will shows it on Serial Monitor as what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer per se.

Posted as an answer because of attached images.

It is unclear what you are actually asking.

I ran a python minimal web server in the same folder as index.html.

Here is the trace from the server.

```
C:\Users\qwerty\Desktop2\MinimalExamples-main\22-1-25_query_parameters_submitButton\data>py3 -m http.server 80
Serving HTTP on :: port 80 (http://[::]:80/) ...
::1 - - [27/Jan/2022 15:43:23] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::1 - - [27/Jan/2022 15:43:24] code 404, message File not found
::1 - - [27/Jan/2022 15:43:24] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
::1 - - [27/Jan/2022 15:43:25] "GET /selection.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::1 - - [27/Jan/2022 15:43:32] "GET /?size=2&speed=1&circle=3 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::1 - - [27/Jan/2022 15:43:34] code 404, message File not found
::1 - - [27/Jan/2022 15:43:34] "GET /notMinimal.html HTTP/1.1" 404 -
::1 - - [27/Jan/2022 15:43:39] "GET /?size=1&speed=2&circle=3 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::1 - - [27/Jan/2022 15:45:07] "GET /?size=1&speed=2&square=4 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::1 - - [27/Jan/2022 15:52:46] code 404, message File not found
::1 - - [27/Jan/2022 15:52:46] "GET /notMinimal.html HTTP/1.1" 404 -
::1 - - [27/Jan/2022 15:53:02] "GET /?size=2&speed=1&square=4 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

This is what `index.html` is called with.
The data is available to index.html. You only have to parse it from the URL.

[image]

[image]